# Best way to route internet through remote comptuer

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, proxy, routing

Alright, I'm not from the US and I pay for a VM running Windows Server 2012 in the USA.

I have full access to that VM and I can install whatever I want on it.

I want to be able to re-route my internet connection through that remote machine in the US so that I can get an IP address that's US based.

What would be the best/easiest way of achieving this?

Comment: Is the US based IP the only reason you are paying for the VM in USA?

Comment: It's not the reason I'm playing for the VM in the first place, no.
I don't really want to log in using remote desktop either since a lot of the content is too interactive or graphical in nature.

I'd rather be able to simply activate something and then my computer's internet would be routed through that remote machine, but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: A service like proxpn has everything done for you. You can have exit point in several countries. Downside it cost between $7-$10 a month depending on contract length.  Otherwise I would use a VPN server.

Comment: Is setting up a VPN a lot of work?

Comment: In general no, but dozens of different companies make VPN servers

Answer (score 0):

I would use a VPN or setup a proxy server. Also you could use Remote Desktop connect to the PC and surf that way.

Comment: Here is 1 possible option: http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/